Fuzz-test the performance of SmokeDetector's keywords regex
I had an idea for attempting to detect bad performing regexes in Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector, by using Atheris (a fuzzer for python code).
The theory behind it is that a bad performing regex will most likely consume large amounts of stack space in the regex matcher.
Here is the Python code I'm fuzzing with.
#!/usr/bin/python
import atheris

with atheris.instrument_imports():
    import regex
    import sys

from globalvars import GlobalVars

from helpers import get_bookended_keyword_regex_text_from_entries
from findspam import URL_REGEX, REPEATED_CHARACTER_RATIO, city_list

MONOLITHIC = regex.compile(get_bookended_keyword_regex_text_from_entries(GlobalVars.watched_keywords.keys()), regex.UNICODE, city=city_list, ignore_unused=True)

@atheris.instrument_func
def has_few_characters(s):
    uniques = len(set(s) - {"\n", "\t"})
    length = len(s)
    thresholds = [  # LBound, UBound, MaxUnique
        (30, 36, 6), (36, 42, 7), (42, 48, 8), (48, 54, 9), (54, 60, 10),
        (60, 70, 11), (70, 80, 12), (80, 90, 13), (90, 100, 14), (100, 2**30, 15),
    ]
    if any([t[0] <= length < t[1] and uniques <= t[2] for t in thresholds]):
        return True, "Contains {} unique character{}".format(uniques, "s" if uniques >= 2 else "")
    return False, ""

@atheris.instrument_func
def has_repeating_characters(s):
    s = s.strip().replace("\u200B", "").replace("\u200C", "")  # Strip leading and trailing spaces
    if "\n\n" in s or "<code>" in s or "<pre>" in s:
        return False, ""
    s = URL_REGEX.sub("", s)  # Strip URLs for this check
    if not s:
        return False, ""
    # Don't detect a couple of common ways for people to try to include tables (reduces FP by ~20%).
    if regex.search(r"(?:(?:----+|====+)[+|]+){2}", s):
        return False, ""
    # matches = regex.compile(r"([^\s_.,?!=~*/0-9-])(\1{9,})", regex.UNICODE).findall(s)
    matches = regex.compile(r"([^\s\d_.])(\1{9,})", regex.UNICODE).findall(s)
    match = "".join(["".join(match) for match in matches])
    if len(match) / len(s) >= REPEATED_CHARACTER_RATIO:  # Repeating characters make up >= 20 percent
        return True, "{}".format(", ".join(
            ["{}*{}".format(repr(match[0]), len(''.join(match))) for match in matches]))
    return False, ""

@atheris.instrument_func
def runbench(string: str):
    estimate = max(MONOLITHIC.scanner(string).bench()[1:])
    if estimate >= (1 << 20):
        raise ValueError(f'BOOM! [[[{string!r}]]] !BOOM')
    # note: unrolled for loop here
    # because atheris doesn't properly instrument it
    if estimate >= (127 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (126 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (125 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (124 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (123 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (122 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (121 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (120 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (119 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (118 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (117 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (116 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (115 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (114 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (113 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (112 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (111 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (110 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (109 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (108 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (107 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (106 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (105 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (104 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (103 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (102 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (101 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (100 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (99 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (98 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (97 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (96 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (95 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (94 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (93 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (92 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (91 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (90 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (89 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (88 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (87 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (86 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (85 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (84 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (83 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (82 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (81 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (80 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (79 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (78 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (77 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (76 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (75 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (74 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (73 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (72 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (71 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (70 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (69 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (68 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (67 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (66 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (65 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (64 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (63 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (62 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (61 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (60 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (59 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (58 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (57 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (56 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (55 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (54 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (53 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (52 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (51 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (50 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (49 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (48 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (47 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (46 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (45 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (44 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (43 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (42 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (41 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (40 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (39 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (38 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (37 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (36 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (35 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (34 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (33 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (32 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (31 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (30 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (29 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (28 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (27 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (26 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (25 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (24 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (23 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (22 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (21 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (20 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (19 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (18 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (17 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (16 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (15 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (14 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (13 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (12 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (11 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (10 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (9 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (8 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (7 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (6 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (5 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (4 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (3 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (2 << 13): break
    elif estimate >= (1 << 13): break

@atheris.instrument_func
def TestAllWatchedKeywords(data: bytes):
    if len(data) < 1:
        return

    fdp = atheris.FuzzedDataProvider(data)

    string = fdp.ConsumeUnicode(len(data))

    if len({'\0', '\r', '\n'} & set(string)) > 0:
        return

    if has_few_characters(string)[0]:
        return
    
    if has_repeating_characters(string)[0]:
        return

    runbench(string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    atheris.Setup(sys.argv, TestAllWatchedKeywords)
    atheris.Fuzz()

If cloning the entire SmokeDetector repository is undesirable, you may replace up to the definition of MONOLITHIC and set the MONOLITHIC regex with your favourite pattern: such as regex.compile('a+a+a+')
#!/usr/bin/python
import atheris

with atheris.instrument_imports():
    import regex
    import sys

URL_REGEX = regex.compile("")
REPEATED_CHARACTER_RATIO = 0.2

MONOLITHIC = regex.compile('a+a+a+')

(In order to run, you need to patch regex with the below patch, [so that it can expose the maximum internal stack sizes], and pip install .)
diff --git a/regex_3/_regex.c b/regex_3/_regex.c
index 9164e75..2485cc7 100644
--- a/regex_3/_regex.c
+++ b/regex_3/_regex.c
@@ -447,6 +447,7 @@ typedef struct RE_RepeatOneStateData {
 typedef struct ByteStack {
     size_t capacity;
     size_t count;
+    size_t utilized_max;
     BYTE* storage;
 } ByteStack;
 
@@ -471,6 +472,7 @@ typedef struct RE_State {
     Py_ssize_t lastgroup;
     /* Info about the repeats. */
     RE_RepeatData* repeats;
+    Py_ssize_t backtracking; /* How many times we pop from any stack */
     Py_ssize_t search_anchor; /* Where the last match finished. */
     Py_ssize_t match_pos; /* The start position of the match. */
     Py_ssize_t text_pos; /* The current position of the match. */
@@ -594,6 +596,9 @@ typedef struct MatchObject {
     Py_ssize_t lastgroup; /* Last named group seen by the engine (-1 if none). */
     size_t group_count; /* The number of groups. */
     RE_GroupData* groups; /* The capture groups. */
+    Py_ssize_t max_sstack_size; /* Maximum sstack size */
+    Py_ssize_t max_bstack_size; /* Maximum bstack size */
+    Py_ssize_t max_pstack_size; /* Maximum pstack size */
     PyObject* regs;
     size_t fuzzy_counts[RE_FUZZY_COUNT];
     RE_FuzzyChange* fuzzy_changes;
@@ -2264,6 +2269,7 @@ Py_LOCAL_INLINE(BOOL) safe_check_cancel(RE_State* state) {
 Py_LOCAL_INLINE(BOOL) ByteStack_init(RE_State* state, ByteStack* stack) {
     stack->capacity = 0;
     stack->count = 0;
+    stack->utilized_max = 0;
     stack->storage = NULL;
 
     return TRUE;
@@ -2275,11 +2281,13 @@ Py_LOCAL_INLINE(void) ByteStack_fini(RE_State* state, ByteStack* stack) {
     stack->storage = NULL;
     stack->capacity = 0;
     stack->count = 0;
+    stack->utilized_max = 0;
 }
 
 /* Resets a stack of bytes. */
 Py_LOCAL_INLINE(void) ByteStack_reset(RE_State* state, ByteStack* stack) {
     stack->count = 0;
+    stack->utilized_max = 0;
 }
 
 /* Pushes a byte onto a stack of bytes. */
@@ -2311,6 +2319,8 @@ Py_LOCAL_INLINE(BOOL) ByteStack_push(RE_State* state, ByteStack* stack, BYTE
 
     stack->storage[stack->count++] = item;
 
+    if (stack->utilized_max < stack->count) stack->utilized_max = stack->count;
+
     return TRUE;
 }
 
@@ -2351,6 +2361,8 @@ Py_LOCAL_INLINE(BOOL) ByteStack_push_block(RE_State* state, ByteStack* stack,
     Py_MEMCPY(stack->storage + stack->count, block, count);
     stack->count = new_count;
 
+    if (stack->utilized_max < stack->count) stack->utilized_max = stack->count;
+
     return TRUE;
 }
 
@@ -2362,6 +2374,8 @@ Py_LOCAL_INLINE(BOOL) ByteStack_pop(RE_State* state, ByteStack* stack, BYTE*
 
     *item = stack->storage[--stack->count];
 
+    state->backtracking++;
+
     return TRUE;
 }
 
@@ -2374,6 +2388,8 @@ Py_LOCAL_INLINE(BOOL) ByteStack_pop_block(RE_State* state, ByteStack* stack,
     stack->count -= count;
     Py_MEMCPY(block, stack->storage + stack->count, count);
 
+    state->backtracking++;
+
     return TRUE;
 }
 
@@ -18135,6 +18151,8 @@ Py_LOCAL_INLINE(BOOL) state_init_2(RE_State* state, PatternObject* pattern,
 
     state->thread_state = NULL;
 
+    state->backtracking = 0;
+
     ByteStack_init(state, &state->sstack);
     ByteStack_init(state, &state->bstack);
     ByteStack_init(state, &state->pstack);
@@ -20677,6 +20695,21 @@ static PyObject* scanner_match(ScannerObject* self, PyObject* unused) {
     return scanner_search_or_match(self, FALSE);
 }
 
+/* ScannerObject's 'bench' method. */
+static PyObject* scanner_bench(ScannerObject* self, PyObject* unused) {
+    PyObject* my_match = scanner_search_or_match(self, TRUE);
+    BOOL is_match = my_match != Py_None;
+    Py_DECREF(my_match);
+    RE_State state = self->state;
+    return Py_BuildValue(
+        "(innnn)",
+        is_match,
+        state.sstack.utilized_max,
+        state.bstack.utilized_max,
+        state.pstack.utilized_max,
+        state.backtracking);
+}
+
 /* ScannerObject's 'search' method. */
 static PyObject* scanner_search(ScannerObject* self, PyObject* unused) {
     return scanner_search_or_match(self, TRUE);
@@ -20730,6 +20763,12 @@ PyDoc_STRVAR(scanner_match_doc,
     "match() --> MatchObject or None.\n\
     Match at the current position in the string.");
 
+PyDoc_STRVAR(scanner_bench_doc,
+    "bench() --> Tuple(int, int, int, int, int).\n\
+    Search from the current position in the string.\n\
+    Returns 1 if match, else 0 and after that\n\
+    mysterious benchmarking stats.");
+
 PyDoc_STRVAR(scanner_search_doc,
     "search() --> MatchObject or None.\n\
     Search from the current position in the string.");
@@ -20737,6 +20776,7 @@ PyDoc_STRVAR(scanner_search_doc,
 /* ScannerObject's methods. */
 static PyMethodDef scanner_methods[] = {
     {"match", (PyCFunction)scanner_match, METH_NOARGS, scanner_match_doc},
+    {"bench", (PyCFunction)scanner_bench, METH_NOARGS, scanner_bench_doc},
     {"search", (PyCFunction)scanner_search, METH_NOARGS, scanner_search_doc},
     {"__copy__", (PyCFunction)scanner_copy, METH_NOARGS},
     {"__deepcopy__", (PyCFunction)scanner_deepcopy, METH_O},

Does the above python fuzzer and patch follow good practices? Is there perhaps performance improvements I can incorporate? Key performance indicators include how many exec/s it reaches while fuzzing and how long it takes for the fuzzer to find a crashing example (note that it deliberately crashes for a sufficiently large example, this is caught by atheris and generates a file with a name like the pattern crash-<hash>.)

You're using some sophisticated techniques, and seem to be proposing an interesting approach. But I can't tell what the problem is you're trying to solve and how effective the approach is, as I can't see any concrete inputs + outputs, nor a cogent problem statement about what is originally Bad and then how the KPI winds up being improved. I don't know how to measure your KPI. I invite you to edit the Question so it offers additional details. Also, I have no idea what "1/1b corp entries" might possibly denote. // Please comment on NFA vs DFA regex engine speed in this context. And what is "SD"?

No. What you did mention was "slow", and NFAs (while smaller) are slower than linear-time DFAs. The original Bell Labs regex engine was very fast. PCRE offers additional features, but at the expense of making patterns like a.*b.*c.*d very expensive, and it is entirely too easy for a newbie to accidentally write such a regex. I am trying hard to understand what problem you're attempting to solve and how one approach is an improvement over another approach. I am not a robot. Please make the comparison concrete by presenting alternate input+output pairs together with timing results.

regarding 1/1b corp entries - these numbers are supposed to go upwards as the fuzzer determines new coverage cases.

Ok, so it seems we're talking about fuzzing e.g. the 1121 regexes in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/master/blacklisted_usernames.txt , got it. That was not immediately apparent. I found https://pypi.org/project/GlobalVars , but I have no idea what import blacklists means, nor does pip install. It would be helpful if you'd post a GitHub repo link. I currently cannot reproduce the results of your automated test suite. I'm still waiting for the (giant!) llvm-project.git repo to download to my Mac. And as far as 1/1b corp entries going upwards, I am still ignorant.

Sorry, I'm still looking for the canonical reference that explains why PCRE DFA catastrophic backtracking readily leads to (accidental) exponential time complexity, and what to do about it. Which is to prefer a (bigger) NFA. However I did locate Ken Thompson in 1968 bad mouthing a DFA which "executes slowly": https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/363347.363387 . Alas, I lack an IBM 7094 on which to run the code. // Aha! Found it: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html . Russ Cox is saying a fuzzer could easily DoS PCRE.

"So far it's working well, but hasn't found any examples that take up too much time." If finding such examples is the goal, what part of the code is working well? Have you verified your code will produce what you're looking for with tests, automatic or otherwise?

I'm well aware of Smoke Detector, but what dataset are you testing the regex against? You may think you've provided sufficient details because you'vr been working with your code for a while. For an outside reviewer though, your question seems light on details.
